# Adding query string to url already indexed, will cause problem with SEO?

Tags: seo, web-development, query-string

I have to change the urls of my site, from something like:

www.site.com/page.html

to

www.site.com/page.html?value=randomvalue

This will cause problems with SEO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google allow you to declare the purpose of query string parameters within Webmaster Tools. According to Google:

> In general, URL parameters fall into one of two categories:
>
> **Parameters that don't change page content**: for example, sessionid,
>   affiliateid. Parameters like these are often used to track visits and
>   referrers. They have no affect on the actual content of the page.
>
> **Parameters that change or determine the content of a page**: for
>   example, brand, gender, country, sortorder.

If Google have already crawled pages with query strings then they may already appear on the URL Paramaters page in Webmaster Tools. Otherwise you can just click to **Add parameter** for any new ones.

[image: Webmaster Tools URL Parameters]

If the parameter doesn't affect the content displayed to the user, select **No** in the **Does this parameter change** list, and then click **Save**. If the parameter does affect the display of content, click **Yes: Changes, reorders, or narrows page content**, and then select how you want Google to crawl URLs with this parameter.

For more information read the Webmaster Tools help page on [URL Parameters](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1235687?hl=en).

Comment: It's also a good idea to use canonical URLs as John Conde mentioned, but this helps cover all bases and is specifically tailored to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If entirely new content is pulled up when that querystring is present, no, you will be fine. If the same content is pulled up with only a minor variation due to that querystring then, yes, you will have duplicate content issues.

Fortunately that is easily resolved by using [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html). Just make the non-querystring URL the canonical URL and you'll be just fine.